# Do I have five dollars?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I'm not made of paper, although people say that, and
If you think back far enough, a Chevy on the land.
One more rhyme may help you find the answer that you seek,
So keep in mind that every year I'm honored with a week.

---

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it must be a:

> A shark

Because:

> They can be made of paper like origami using a 5$ bill

And:

> Chevy Chase was the Land Shark on Saturday Night Live

And:

> There is an annual shark week that began in about 1987 or so

Comment: Correct for the target, but the first part was because some folks say "Card Shark," rather than "Card Sharp."  The rest is spot on, so you get the green check.